# XNA: Object not drawn on screen

Tags: c#, xna, draw

I am known with drawing textures on the screen with XNA. I just can't get this to work.
I do load the texture correctly.

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null,
            selectedLevel.GetCamera().getViewMatrix(new Vector2(1.0f)));

        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
        foreach (MovableObject movableObject in selectedLevel.movableObjects)
        {
            if (movableObject is Enemy)
            {
                Enemy enemy = (Enemy)movableObject;
                ThrowAttack attack = ((ThrowAttack)enemy.getAttack());
                if (attack != null && attack.getThrowObject() != null)
                {
                    attack.getThrowObject().Texture = TextureLoader.GetInstance().GetTexture(attack.getThrowObject().TextureName);
                    attack.getThrowObject().Animate(Direction.Right, gameTime);
                    attack.getThrowObject().Walk(Direction.Right, 2f);
                    attack.getThrowObject().Update(gameTime);
                    attack.getThrowObject().Draw(spriteBatch);
                }
            }
        }
spriteBatch.End();
base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

the draw in the attack object:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, SpriteRectangle, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
}
```

the texture and position variables in the above .draw method work. Just not with the particular texture in the foreach loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it throw an exception or just not appear on the screen? Are the `position` and `SpriteRectangle` variables reasonable in the debugger?

Comment: SpriteRectangle is 0,0. But also on the sprites that ARE drawn. And yes, the problem is that I get no errors/whatever. It's just not shown but does update (move around).

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you know it moves around if you can't see it?

Comment: Magic! Haha, no I debugged the position. It does change (horizonally all the time). But the weird thing is, everything draws with this method. Just not this Texture I guess? Which is weird because I use this texture somewhere else and that does show.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong, though I haven't fully checked your call against the docs yet

Comment: It is allowed to load a texture and use it multiple times right..?

Comment: yeah, that will work no problem. Really stupid question. It does actually get *into* that draw call, right?

Comment: Yes, I debugged that. It gets into that draw call. The position, texture etc are all correct in that specific draw call.

Comment: No idea then. The only other thing I can think of is that something is erasing/drawing over it.

Comment: Un.Be.Lievable.. Your last comment did it haha. I made the rookie mistake of drawing this item, and then the background image... Thanks mate haha! Another one for my "Don't ever do that" book!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct, so it probably *is* being drawn.

Make sure that nothing else (like another sprite, or the background) is drawing over it. This will happen so quickly that it will look like its not being drawn at all.